# Upload .raw files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have a Python script that try to upload files on google storage but keeps appearing this error:

> googleapiclient.errors.UnknownFileType:

Here is my code:

```
def create_service():

    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    return build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

service=create_service()

request=service.objects().insert(bucket='testBucket',name='test.raw',media_body=path_files+file_raw)

response=request.execute()

exit()
```

`file_raw` is an audio .raw file.

The libraries I am using are:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from google.cloud import storage
```

Comment: Hello, could you just add a better indentation for your code and also specify which are the libraries you are using to upload on google storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, because your file ends in ".raw", the "mimetypes" library is having trouble guessing the content type you want for the object. Try explicitly specifying the "media_mime_type" keyword argument with the MIME type you want GCS to use.

This is where I think the error is likely being generated: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L789

Also, may I suggest that you take a look at the [Google Cloud Client Library for Python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/). I found it nicer to use.